# ALLSELECTED differences in Excel and PowerBI

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I have written the following DAX code currently in use in PowerBI:

```
Accumulated Arrival Quantity (Port) = 
SUMX(
  FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED(
            'Graph Table'[Vessel],
            'Graph Table'[Voyage Number],
            'Graph Table'[Table],
            'Graph Table'[Index],
            'Graph Table'[Arrival Quantity]),
        'Graph Table'[Arrival Quantity] >= 0 && 'Graph Table'[Table] = "Ports" && 'Graph Table'[Index] <= 
   MAX('Graph Table'[Index])),
'Graph Table'[Arrival Quantity])
```

This code correctly calculates the accumulated arrival quantity of fuel for every vessel selected, and every voyage number selected.

However, when I try to write the similar code in Excel, I get the following error:
" This formula is invalid or incomplete: 'Too many arguments were passed to the ALLSELECTED function. The maximum argument count for the function is 1.'. ".

I use Excel 2016. I tried to replicate it in Microsoft 365, but received the same error.

I was wondering if support for DAX is different in PowerBI vs Excel?

Eagerly awaiting replies.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use the whole 'Graph Table' as ALLSELECTED() argument?
I mean, ALLSELECTED in previous versions of DAX can be used with three different types of parameters:
a single column,
a whole table,
or no parameter at all.